# Django: local variable 'five_image' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am using [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data) method to return variables inside a SessionWizardView. However I keep getting the bellow error when I try to return `five_image`, `six_image` or `seven_image'.

> local variable 'five_image' referenced before assignment

What I cant understand is that each of these variables are clearly assigned a value, which I know works as I print it to terminal.

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to store the names of the images which are displayed on pages 5, 6 and 7 of my form for use on a later page.

```
path_one_images = ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg', 'P4D4.jpg', 'P5D5.jpg/', 'P6D6.jpg', 'P7D7.jpg', 'P8D8.jpg', 'P9D9.jpg']


class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  

        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','9','10','11','13','14','15']:
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)   

            if self.steps.current == '5':
                five_image = display_image

            elif self.steps.current == '6':
                six_image = display_image

            elif self.steps.current == '7':
                seven_image = display_image    

            steps = ['5','6','7','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']              
            context.update({'display_image': display_image,
                            'five_image': five_image,
                            'six_image': six_image,
                            'seven_image': seven_image,
                            'steps': steps
                             })                 
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        if self.steps.current in ['8','12','16']:
            print '\n\n\n\nYou are on step', self.steps.current

        return context
```

Any help is as always, much appriciated.

Comment: You are not initializing the various local variables outside the if statements. Hence the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those if statements are mutually exclusive. There's *absolutely no way* all three of them could be assigned a value: only one of them can be. The others will be undefined.

Instead of creating these variables, you would be better off assigning keys in the context directly:

```
        if self.steps.current == '5':
            context['five_image'] = display_image

        elif self.steps.current == '6':
            context['six_image'] = display_image

        elif self.steps.current == '7':
            context['seven_image'] = display_image
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time self.steps.current is not equal to "5" the variable five_image is not being created. Then in context.update you are trying to use a variable that does not exist. You'll need to rework your logic or create the variables before the if statement. The following will fix the error but I still think you'll need to take a hard look at your logic and do some refactoring.

```
path_one_images = ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg', 'P4D4.jpg', 'P5D5.jpg/', 'P6D6.jpg', 'P7D7.jpg', 'P8D8.jpg', 'P9D9.jpg']


class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)         
        five_image = None
        six_image = None
        seven_image = None

        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','9','10','11','13','14','15']:
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)   
            if self.steps.current == '5':
                five_image = display_image

            elif self.steps.current == '6':
                six_image = display_image

            elif self.steps.current == '7':
                seven_image = display_image    

            steps = ['5','6','7','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']              
            context.update({'display_image': display_image,
                            'five_image': five_image,
                            'six_image': six_image,
                            'seven_image': seven_image,
                            'steps': steps
                             })                 
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        if self.steps.current in ['8','12','16']:
            print '\n\n\n\nYou are on step', self.steps.current

        return context
```